# Transforming string into tabular row

Tags: tables, etoolbox, xstring, ampersand

Trying to have a command converting a string into a (tabular) row, where each cell of the row is (a function of) each character of the string. (`\tilerow` is my attempt, `\tiletext` is just for debugging).

I guess my problem is with the protection of `&` (ampersand) because the text version works as it should---it just separates characters with `\&`. And I would like to do the same for the closing `\\` (double backslash). (I currently left a `.` (dot) not to multiply problems.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring,multido}


\title{Title}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\current}{}


%%%\tiletext is just inserting \& and works

\newcommand{\tiletext}[1]
{
\renewcommand{\current}{}
\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{
\StrChar{#1}{\i}[\currentchar]
\eappto\current{\currentchar}
\ifnumless{\i}{5}{\eappto\current{ \protect\& }}{\eappto\current{ . }}
\ifnumless{\i}{5}{}{\current}
}
}

%%%%%\tilerow does not work

\newcommand{\tilerow}[1]
{
\renewcommand{\current}{}
\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{
\StrChar{#1}{\i}[\currentchar]
\eappto\current{\currentchar}
\ifnumless{\i}{5}{\eappto\current{ \protect& }}{\eappto\current{ . }}
\ifnumless{\i}{5}{}{\current}
}
}


\maketitle


%%% this works as intended (returns another string with \& seperation)

\tiletext{bt0f0}


\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\tiletext{bt0f0} \\
\end{tabular}



%%% this doesn't work

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\tilerow{bt0f0}\\
\end{tabular}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your goal?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\multido` uses grouping and when you deliver an `&` TeX gets confused because all cells are groups. Note that `\protect&` does nothing at all, because `&` is not an expandable token.

Here is a LaTeX3 implementation, where I've added also a function that applies to each cell's contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tilerow}{m}
 {% pass the control to an inner function
  \sunless_tilerow:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tiled}{O{5}}
 {% we have an optional argument for the number of columns
  \begin{tabular}{c*{#1}{c}}
 }
 {
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \sunless_function:n #1
 {% define here the action for the various cases; recall that ~ denotes a space
  \str_case:nnn { #1 }
   {
    {a}{There~was~a}
    {b}{Something~with~b}
    {t}{tttttt}
    {0}{ZERO!}
    {1}{TRUE!}
   }
   {OOPS~(#1)} % all other cases
 }

% two variables
\seq_new:N \l_sunless_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_sunless_row_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sunless_tilerow:n #1
 {% clear the sequence where we store `\sunless_function:n {<item>}
  \seq_clear:N \l_sunless_row_seq
  % map the argument token by token
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_sunless_row_seq
     {
      \sunless_function:n { ##1 }
     }
   }
  % deliver the sequence
  \seq_use:Nn \l_sunless_row_seq { & }
  % finish off the row
  \\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tiled}
  \tilerow{bt0f0}
  \tilerow{texSE}
  \tilerow{12345}
\end{tiled}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Thanks to Bruno Le Floch who suggested a simplification.)

Comment: There is in fact no need for storing the result of `\seq_use:Nn` in a token list before using it.  Most `expl3` functions which leave tokens in the input stream will only manipulate those tokens within braces (or fake `\iffalse{\fi`/`\iffalse}\fi` braces) until the very end where they return tokens in the input stream.  So `\seq_use:Nn \l_your_seq { & } \\` in a tabular is safe.

Comment: Ah, also you can use `\seq_set_map:NNn` (in `l3candidates`), so the body of your `\sunless_tilerow:n` becomes `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_sunless_row_seq { } {#1} \seq_set_map:NNn \l_sunless_row_seq \l_sunless_row_seq { \exp_not:N \sunless_function:n {##1} }`.  I think I added this function for precisely those kinds of cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want.

I couldn't find the source of your error, but I rewrote your code in a slightly simpler fashion, and it seemed to work after that! I'm using the TikZ `\foreach` command rather than `\multido`, just because I'm more used to that, no other reason.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tilerow}[1]{
  \foreach\i in {1,2,...,5} {
    \StrChar{#1}{\i}[\currentchar]
    \ifnum\i=1
      \xdef\current{\currentchar}
    \else
      \xdef\current{\current & \currentchar}
    \fi
  }
  \current\\
}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \tilerow{bt0f0}
  \tilerow{texSE}
  \tilerow{12345}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: The key difference between what the OP did and what you did is that they used the contents of `\current` within the loop (with the condition "is this the last iteration?").  Unfortunately, `\multido` (and I believe `\foreach` too) works within a group to allow for nesting (well there are other ways to allow nesting).  This group interferes with the tabular, hence the error `forgotten \endgroup`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Hmm, not sure I understand your explanation. *My* solution uses `\current` within the loop too.

Comment: No, it builds `\current` within the loop, but `\current\\` is outside.  More precisely, within the loop, the contents of `\current` are only inserted in the input stream within braces (the `\xdef` construction), and the first time they appear without braces is at `\current\\`, when the loop has ended.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Would you think that a `\seq_use:NNn` macro is feasible? The second argument should be a one argument function to be applied to each item of the sequence; the third should be the separator between items.

Comment: @egreg: I thought of that.  It is feasible, but a bit messy, and I don't want to approach that situation like this.  A better approach would be if we could manipulate sequences as `n`-type arguments (simply the result of `V` expansion on a seq, no need to know the internal structure).  Then `\seq_use:fn { \seq_apply:NN \l_your_seq \function:n } { separator }` would be feasible, rather than defining a new functino for any combination of needs.